# OK "User was removed" but what was the answer for which I earned and then lost rep points?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, user-accounts, deleted-posts

From time to time I lose 10 rep points for a "User was removed" reason. I'm really curios to know in what way I helped that user, that is, what was his\her question, and what did I answer? Currently, there's no way to know that and trace back my answer.  Can SO add a link for the origin of the Rep points lost?

Comment: I must admit I'm also often curious. There's no real need to know what question it was, but its cruel to tell us half of something but then say; "But the rest is secret"

Comment: keep in mind it may be more than one question. If a user had voted on many of your answers or questions recently (a new developer in a tag where you're active, for example) then you would lose more than 5 or 10 points. See the top Related question - 865 points!

Comment: When you see "user was removed", it is because that user voted on your posts, and those votes were removed.  If you answered a question of theirs that was deleted, you would see the answer's title (and a link if you have 10K),

Comment: The reason why it's doesn't tell us is protect the anonymity of the votes from the deleted user. Not that everyone agrees with this position - since the user is well... deleted. And it's possible to abuse the vote caching to figure out what the posts are.

Comment: But I dont want to know anything about the user, just the answer...

Comment: @natan the (hottly disputed) position of the community is that it would reveal the voting history of the user.

Comment: But, that user was removed, so a. what does it matter? b. How would I know, unless that users wrote a comment thanking me (+1) etc...

Comment: @natan While it is not common, there is precedent of a high profile user leaving and many of his/her votes being rescinded.  So everyone would know who left and how he voted.

Comment: @natan but in the end, I guess my response there is "why does it matter".  I certainly am curious when it happens to me, but in the end it doesn't matter, they are just imaginary unicorn points.

Comment: :-) yep, but curiosity is a strong force...

Comment: @natan then the best way is to keep track on the votes of your post on a daily basis and then compare after the user was removed ;-)

Comment: @natan Not that long ago a user decided to leave a site. The process did not really go as it was supposed to, leading to several users guessing the source of gained or lost rep. Suffice it to say that this user was less than happy to have his anonymity lost when all he wanted was to leave.